# handling Postbacks From other website to My website

Tags: node.js, express, post, postback

Im using [SuperRewards](http://www.superrewards.com/) (SR) To make Coin transaction for users in my website,maybe you are familiar with SR.
Whenever a transaction happens **SuperRewards sends a postback** (Post Request) to my server containing information about the transaction and coins etc...
**So my question** is how to handle Postbacks or Post request ( i really dont know the diffrence ) from other website to my server USing **Nodejs Express** ?
[Picture 1 App testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYdys.png)  
[picture 2 app Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXaPv.png)
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX8aW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the support team and they told me i must use a public domain not Local host that s why it wasnt working so the problem is solved and thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You would handle it like any other request coming to your Express app. Since it's a `GET` request, you would have a `GET` route defined.

According to section [Fields and Formats](http://docs.superrewards.com/docs/notification-postbacks#fields-and-formats), you get back quite a few query strings. Knowing that we can do the following:

```
app.get('/super-rewards', async (req, res) => {
  // `new` is a reserved keyword, so we can't use `new` as a variable name.
  const newCurrency = req.query['new']

  const {
    id,
    uid,
    oid,
    total,
    sig
  } = req.query
})
```

Additionally, the documentation states that `sig` should match the MD5 hash of your `secret key`, if I'm understanding that correctly. So a full example would be something like:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/super-rewards', async (req, res) => {
  // `new` is a reserved keyword, so we can't use `new` as a variable name.
  const newCurrency = req.query['new']

  const {
    id,
    uid,
    oid,
    total,
    sig
  } = req.query

  const secretHash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(process.env.SECRET_KEY).digest('hex')
  if (secretHash !== sig) {
    throw new Error('Invalid transaction')
  }
})
```

Aside, it is a `GET` request because the documentation clearly states that:

> Postbacks are sent from our server to yours using a HTTP GET request (...)

Comment: there was an option in app settings which changes the requests to POST Req (it was checked)  but it doesnt matter now i changed it to GET REQ.  i used ur code However while Testing =>  req.query was an empty object. 
So i added a screenshot of the testing page in super Rewards and tell me if i did something wrong

Comment: Try `req.params`. Although the query string shouldn't be an empty object since the docs state that `(...) request with these fields in the query string`

Comment: Both req.params and req.query are empty.
what i do is i send test postbacks to my server then i manually go to Postback URL (http://localhost:3000/checkcoins) then i get the empty objects ... i dont think im doing something